# Shall I move the method from service to its own class, or not?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, service, transactions

In a java project, we have a fat service class which contains many methods:

```
@Service
@Transaction
public class FatService {

   @Autowired
   private FatRepository fatRepository;

   public void doSomethingSpecial() {
      // complex logic
      fatRepository.save(foo);
      fatRepository.save(bar);
   }

   public void doSomething1() {}
   public void doSomething2() {}
   public void doSomething3() {}
   public void doSomething4() {}
   public void doSomething5() {}
   public void doSomething6() {}
   public void doSomething7() {}
   public void doSomething8() {}

}
```

This service is meant to provide a transaction boundary for all classes in the codebase. It has some database operations. We just need to maintain this class if we concern transactions.

But it's fat, and I find there are some methods which are only used in some other single classes, e.g. `doSomethingSpecial()`, it only used in class `Special`:

```
@Component
class Special {
    @Autowired
    private FatService fatService;

    doSomething() {
        // do something first

        fatService.doSomethingSpecial();

        // do something last
    }
}
```

I don't feel like to split the logic into two different classes, so I move the `doSomethingSpecial()` method from `FatService` to `Special`:

```
@Component
class Special {
    @Autowired
    private FatService fatService;

    doSomething() {
        // do something first

        doSomethingSpecial();

        // do something last
    }

    @Transactional
    private doSomethingSpecial() {
       // this method is move from FatService
       fatService.save(foo);
       fatService.save(bar);
    }
}
```

Notice I still keep the `@Transactional` annotation on the method `doSomethingSpecial`. Also add a `save` method to `FatService`:

```
public void save(Object obj) {
    fatRepository.save(obj);
}
```

But my colleague says I should not move it into `Speical`, because we have to manage transactions in two different classes, which makes the code hard to maintain if the transaction spreads through all code base.

I want to know what is the best solution?

1. I don't want the logic split into different classes just because of transaction
2. I still want the transaction management easy

Answer (score 2):

Basically everything in a typical application involving a database is transactional. So, unless your application is a tiny toy application, putting every transactional method in a single class is not manageable: you'll end up with a class with hundreds or thousands of methods. If you have a layered application, every service anyway should be transactional, and this only needs one annotation, so there's not much to manage.

That said, your refactoring has a serious bug: despite the fact that the `Special.doSomethingSpecial()` method is annotated as transactional, it's actually not, because it's a private method called directly from another method of the same class. So the transactional Spring interceptor can't intercept the method call and handle the transaction. In short, `@Transactional` works only when a Spring bean calls **another** Spring bean.

Comment: Thanks but sorry, I can't understand the first paragraph well. Do you agree provide a single service class, or several service classes? And do we need to keep transaction always in service layer?

Comment: What the first paragraph is saying is that putting all the transactionsl methods in a single class doesn't scale: you'll end up with hundreds of methods in a single class. So yes, obviously, you should have several, transactional, service classes.

Answer (score 0):

the fat service may be your business responsibility separate not clearly,you should re-think bounded context,split fat service to different context and rename the service according ubiquitous language.not suggest move method into Special class,it will let service layer meaningless which like quench a thirst with poison.